# Cloud Document AI API has not been used in project xxxxxx before or it is disabled

Tags: google-ai-platform, cloud-document-ai

While calling google document api, getting below error. apis are enabled, even after waiting for few hours still getting same error. any suggestion

RpcException: Status(StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="Cloud Document AI API has not been used in project xxxxxxx before or it is disabled.
Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/documentai.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxxx then retry.
If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1646997388.673000000","description":
"Error received from peer ipv4:234.234324.324234:443","file":"......\src\core\lib\surface\call.cc","file_line":1070,"grpc_message":
"Cloud Document AI API has not been used in project xxxxxx before or it is disabled.
Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/documentai.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxx then retry.
If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.","grpc_status":7}")

```
 ByteString content = ByteString.CopyFrom(bytes);

            DocumentProcessorServiceClient documentProcessorServiceClient = new DocumentProcessorServiceClientBuilder
            { CredentialsPath = "D:\\poised-aleph-3xx-6a3xxxx4343a03.json" }
            .Build();

            ProcessRequest request = new ProcessRequest
            {
                ProcessorName = ProcessorName.FromProjectLocationProcessor("invoiceprocessor", "us", "343431"),
                SkipHumanReview = true,
                RawDocument = new RawDocument
                {
                    MimeType = "application/pdf",
                    Content = content
                }
            };

            request.RawDocument.MimeType = "application/pdf";
            request.RawDocument.Content = content;

            // Make the request
            ProcessResponse response = await 
 documentProcessorServiceClient.ProcessDocumentAsync(request);
```

---

**after fixing correct project id, as shown in developer console -> Prediction endpoint**

[image]

```
Detail="Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource 
'//documentai.googleapis.com/projects/8xxxxxxxx7/locations/us/processors/axxxxxxxxxx1f' (or it may not exist)."
```

---

**Adding Document AI Role to service account**

[image]

### **final fix**
[image]

Comment: invalid project id used. now this error doesnt appear, but still service failing.

Comment: endpoint : https://us-documentai.googleapis.com/v1/projects/xxxx/locations/us/processors/xxxxx:process

documentclient api throws this error. RpcException: Status(StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource 
'//documentai.googleapis.com/projects/xxxx/locations/us/processors/xxxxxx' (or it may not exist)."  ProjectId, processorId matching with endpointurl in console.

Comment: Hi OP, can you validate that you are using the correct project ID as mentioned by @anand on the above comment?

Comment: @ScottB, projectid, processorid shown in console->predictionendpoint is used in clientapi.

Comment: @ScottB updated original post with recent error details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since @anand (OP) has already fixed the first issue as mentioned on the above updated question, OP got the below recent error

```
RpcException: Status(StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource 
'//documentai.googleapis.com/projects/xxxx/locations/us/processors/xxxxxx' (or it may not exist)."
```

This error is related on  the permission of the service account being used to authenticate the API.

You may update your Serivce Account permission by navigating to **IAM & Admin** > **IAM**
[image]

You may navigate on the list and edit the permission of your service account from that page. You may follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/setup#auth) on how to setup service account authentication for Document AI.

Since your error message shows that you are having issues on `documentai.processors.processOnline`, you may grant the **Cloud DocumentAI API User** role to your service account since it has below permissions which also covered the one on your error message:

`documentai.operations.getLegacy`, `documentai.processors.processOnline`, `documentai.processors.processBatch`.

You may also refer to this [Document AI IAM Roles Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/access-control/iam-roles) for more information on the pre-defined roles for Document AI.

Comment: added documentai api user role to service account. (screenshot attached in OP). and generated new key as well. But still getting "StatusCode="PermissionDenied", Detail="Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource" error.

Comment: it works after providing document api user role to client_email specified in Json. thanks

Comment: @anand, I think you granted your own user the Cloud Document AI API User on your first try instead of the actual service account. A service account is a non-human user that needs to authenticate and be authorized to access data in Google APIs. You mat check out https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#background to know more about service accounts.

Comment: thanks @scottb. it works and updated my OP and marked this as anwer. thanks.